# can python draw markers with a 3d effect?

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, ggplot2, seaborn

Can Python, either using matplotlib or seaborn, draw markers with 3D effect?

Or any other software can do this? (like ggplot in R or origin etc.)

To explain my points, the following graphs are examples:
[image]

[image]

The pink/red/black dots have a 3D effect.

Thank you!

Comment: This question has already been asked at some point. Unfortunately, i cannot find it at the moment. Maybe someone is better at googling than I am.

Comment: Thank you for not deleting this. I can imagine that people have already done this. But I couldn't find related information, except using mathematica with their embedded markers : http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotMarkers.html

Comment: Questions will anyways not deleted, they might just be closed as duplicate. The condition being that someone actually finds that duplicate. ;-) (The answer to the question I'm refering to used a similar approach as below, using an image plot, but in matplotlib instead of R)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example using `ggplot2` in R.
Hope it can help you.

```
library("ggplot2")
library("ggimage")

set.seed(1)
d <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10),  y = rnorm(10),
     image = rep("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/11/26/19/19/ball-1064402_960_720.png",10))

ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) +
geom_line(lwd=3, color="#FF000044") + 
geom_image(aes(image=image), size=.05) + 
theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, i see. The idea is to use an image as the marker ,,, smart! I was thinking of drawing a set of concentric circles and filling them with the same color but different alpha values. Thanks!